# Spring injection with new Window (FXML)

Tags: javafx

I use AnnotationConfigApplicationContext to load my spring configuration.

```
public class Main extends Application {

private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/org/test/view/main.fxml"));
    loader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);
    Parent root = loader.load();
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setOnHidden(e -> Platform.exit());
}
```

and this is my ApplicationConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class ApplicationConfig {

@Bean
public Executor executor() {
    return Executors.newCachedThreadPool(r -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t ;
    });
}
```

Now I would like to inject **this Executor instance** into a new Stage (TestController.fxml) via FXMLLoader. How can I achieve that?

```
public void showNewWindow()  {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/org/test/view/TestController.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();            
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
        stage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

All help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify here? What do you really mean when you say "inject the executor instance into a new stage"? Do you mean inject it into the controller associated with loading `TestController.fxml`? (You can't really inject it into a stage, a stage is a predefined class and has no field for an executor.) And where is the code for `showNewWindow()`? Is that in the controller for `main.fxml`?

Comment: Yes the **showNewWindow()** is in the controller of main.fxml. The point is, if a register the **ApplicationConfig** to the new window again, it will create a new instance of the Executor,  but my goal is to use the same Executor instance for both windows. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject "well-known objects" into spring-managed beans. The application context itself is one such object, so in your main controller you can do:

```
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext ;

    public void showNewWindow()  {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/org/test/view/TestController.fxml"));
            fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);
            Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();            
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

Now the `TestController` will be spring-managed, so you can simply do

```
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private Executor executor ;

    // ...

}
```